# Parser error when trying to Eval()

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm binding to ListView like that:

```
                var authors =  (from a in db.Books
                              where a.Author.StartsWith(letter)
                              group a by a.Author into g
                              select new{Author=g.Key}).ToList();
                ListView1.DataSource = authors;
                ListView1.DataBind();
```

When user clicks on item I need to redirect him to another page with some query string. Here's my ItemTemplate:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <td runat="server" onclick="window.location.href = 'CatalogAutor.aspx?text=<%#Eval("Author") %>';">
       <asp:Label ID="AutorLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Author") %>' />
    </td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

`Eval("Author")` in `asp:Label` works well, but why I'm getting "Parser error: Server tag is not well formed" on Eval in onclick event?
Is there any other way to get Author name from clicked table cell?

Comment: Note that `<td>` isn't an ASP.NET web control like `<asp:Label>` is. I strongly suspect that's the problem. It's been ages since I've one web forms, mind you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the runat=server on the td tag, it will databind the value anyway

So tthis should work:

```
<ItemTemplate>
      <td onclick="window.location.href = 'CatalogAutor.aspx?text=<%#Eval("Author") %>'">
             <asp:Label ID="AutorLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Author") %>' />
       </td>
</ItemTemplate>
```